# How to apply inline CSS to Django form?

Tags: django

I am doing a Django project.  I made a class-based view form in Django and it's shown but how to give stylesheet to that form? It's shown by `{{ form.as_p }}`, but how to design that form?

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a modelform, you can add classes and styles to fields as follows:

```
class SomeModelNameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area', 'placeholder': 'Enter your name'}), required=True)
    credentials = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area', 'placeholder': 'Enter your designation'}), required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModelName
```

This works for any form type

Django Form widgets in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/

Comment: class Book(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(widget= models.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area', 'placeholder': 'Enter your name'}),                                           required=True) 
    message = models.TextField (max_length=1000)
    url = models.CharField (max_length=1000)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    stores = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    brands = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dealtype = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    feature = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=200)

Comment: This would be in your forms.py file. Where you've created your form class.