# Not able to give inline CSS to Django form

Tags: django

Hi i am working on **Django** project but not able to give Inline class. How to apply CSS class in **class-base view form**.

this is my code:

```
class Book(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    message = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    stores = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    brands = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    dealtype = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    feature = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: You have to become much more specific in order to get an answer for that.

Comment: Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking a question. And welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why have you created a new account to post [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31311271/3001761), but with even less information?! Have you tried the answer you got there? What happened?

Comment: Oh my god! He really did that, didn't he! Hilarious.

Comment: this is my codeclass Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    stores = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    brands = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dealtype = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    feature = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=200)

Comment: Oh, for pity's... **edit the question**, don't just dump (unreadable) code into the comments. Also, it would be nice if you'd at least pick one and delete the other. And that still doesn't give enough information to explain what you're doing and where you're stuck; read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi i am working on a Django project. I want to give a class to lable attribute in Django form. Here i created a form using this code

`class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    stores = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    brands = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dealtype = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    feature = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=200)`

Comment: Why have you dumped the same code into a comment again? What help do you think that could possibly be!?

Answer (score 0):

```
forms.py
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def send_email(self):
        # send email using the self.cleaned_data dictionary
        pass
```

Comment: A little explanation of what this does would help here I feel.